# How to add a delay for Angular 2 HTTP calls

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-http

I am using Angular 2 with TypeScript to implement a web application that uses HTTP calls to a REST Server.

The problem is that some GET calls are faster than others and I have to add some delay before them. How can I remove this delays and handle this issue properly?

For example, after I delete one Manufacturer (in the code below), I have to go back to the view where I can see all the Manufacturers (there I implement the GET call inside the ngOnInit()).

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute }   from '@angular/router';
import { DataService } from '../../../data/data.service';
import { CallManufacturerServices } from '../calls/calls.service';
import { ManufacturerClass } from '../class/manufacturer.class';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './app/inventory/manufacturer/view/view.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app/inventory/manufacturer/view/view.component.css'],
    providers: [CallManufacturerServices]
})

export class ViewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private sub: any;
    private ServerData: ManufacturerClass = {
        ManufacturerId: 0,
        ManufacturerName: 'N/D',
        ManufacturerWebSite: 'N/D'
    };

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private data: DataService,
        private calls: CallManufacturerServices) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            let id = +params['id'];
            this.getSingleManufacturer(id);
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

    private getSingleManufacturer(id: number) {
        this.calls.GetSingleManufacturer(id).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.ServerData = data.json();
            },
            error => console.log(error),
            () => console.log('getSingleManufacturer complete!')
       );
    }

    private deleteManufacturer(_manufacturer: ManufacturerClass) {
        this.calls.DeleteManufacturer(_manufacturer.ManufacturerId).subscribe(
            error => console.log(error),
            () => console.log('deleteManufacturer complete!')
        );
        /* this type of delay doesn't work */
        setTimeout(() => {}, 2000); // insert there the delay
        /* when I go to Manufacturer the Get call will start */
        this.goToManufacturer();
    }

    private goToManufacturer() {
        this.router.navigate(['/inventory/manufacturer']);
    }

    private goToEdit(manufacturer: ManufacturerClass) {
         this.router.navigate(['/inventory/manufacturer/edit', manufacturer.ManufacturerId]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use delays. That is doomed to fail, and will slow your app for no reason. You should instead only navigate to the manufacturers route after you got the response of your delete request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have Angular 2 navigate only after the request completes successfully, thus:

```js
this.calls.DeleteManufacturer(_manufacturer.ManufacturerId).subscribe(
        undefined, // onNext handler
        error => console.log(error), // onError handler
        () => { // onComplete handler
            console.log('deleteManufacturer complete!');
            this.goToManufacturer();
        }
    );
```